# Sequelize migration - cursor

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

is there anyway to use cursor in `sequelize migration`? i am trying to create DML script ,the idea is to loop the values in table ie. day using cursor and then insert values to other table ie. mealday inside the cursor.

```
table : day
dayId
dayName

table : meal
mealId
mealName

table : mealday
mealdayId
dayId
mealId
```

the insert statement i should use inside cursor is :

```
insert into mealday (dayId,mealId) 
select **dayIdFromCursor**,mealId from meal
```

Answer (score 0):

as a work around i can simply repeat the `insert` statement 7 times (number of days in day table) and hard code `dayId`

```
insert into mealday (dayId,mealId) 
select 1,mealId from meal

insert into mealday (dayId,mealId) 
select 2,mealId from meal

...

insert into mealday (dayId,mealId) 
select 7,mealId from meal
```